# How to optimize an aggregate query in mongodb (query contains $lookup & $match)

Tags: mongodb, optimization, aggregate, query-optimization, lookup

this query takes 0.75 secs to give 20000 documents. But i want it to happen in between 0.4 secs as i am doing some operations on the query results. I tried with $unwind & $project but it's taking more time.

```
db.getCollection('cases_v2').aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        { "Status": { $ne: "Cancelled-error or trail" } },
        { "BreakDownReason": { $ne: "oldCase" } },
        {
          "CreationDate": {
            $gte: new Date("2021-01-14"),
            $lt: new Date("2021-01-18")
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "services_v2",
      localField: "ServicesRefs",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "ServicesRefs"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "policies_v2",
      localField: "PoliciesRef",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "PoliciesRef"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "vendors_v2",
      localField: "ServicesRefs.selectedSuppliers.supplierId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "vendorDoc"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "locations_v2",
      localField: "ServicesRefs.locationID",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "locDoc"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "vehicles_v2",
      localField: "PoliciesRef.Coverages.VehicleRef",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "vehicleDoc"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "disputes",
      localField: "ServicesRefs.ServiceId",
      foreignField: "serviceId",
      as: "disputeDoc"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Several joins considered as bad practice in NoSQL, you are doing more than 6 lookups i would suggest you to reduce collections, instead of multiple collection put some type field in each document in single collection, second you can create compound index on your matching fields that you are doing in $match stage.

Comment: buy hardware that runs it 2 times faster than what you have now.  I'm quite sure you would need to include details about your environment for anyone to help you.